# KnockoutJS mapping adding new item does not work

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-sortable

I am working on a list which has tasks and subtasks (nested list).. I am implementing KO Sortable in it. Sortable just works fine but when I try to add new task, it does not simply work..

I am using mapping with the following code :

```
    self.Tasks = ko.mapping.fromJS(dummyData);
```

Here is the JSfiddle I am working on :

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/z9fJV/7/

How can I solve the issue?

I also want to add subtasks directly, is there any better way to do it?

One more thing I will be doing in advance. I need to track the priority order in future

Please help me with it :-) Thanks a ton in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In one place, you have "observable" spelled as "observble".

2) In `ko.applyBindings`, you need to instantiate your VM with `new`.

3) Your `click` bindings for `getSelectedTask` need to be qualified with `$root` because it's not a method of the individual task models.

Comment: I am such an idiot.. :P Didn't even notice the spelling mistakes. Effect of late night coding.. Thanks a ton man!